# Recursion Tutorial

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I am learning Java from a book, and come across a chapter regarding recursion using a factorial example.

```
//A simple example of recursion

package tutorials;

class Factorial {
// this is a recursive method
int fact (int n) {
    int result;

    if(n==1) return 1;
    result = fact(n - 1) * n;
    return result;
  }
}

class Recursion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Factorial f = new Factorial();

        System.out.println("Factorial of 3 is " + f.fact(3));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 4 is " + f.fact(4));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 5 is " + f.fact(5));
    }
}
```

The result this piece of code gives is "Factorial of 3 is 6" and "Factorial of 4 is 24"

What i don't understand is what is happening in the class Factorial and why *n is not calculated immediately.  The book does not do a very good job of explaining this so i thought i would ask any experienced programmers for help.

Comment: Because, in computer science and programming in general, you want to save as much computation as possible. doing the recursive  * N is taxing on the system. Putting it down the line and waiting for the recursion to reach "1" is a very desirable method.

Comment: This question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion might be a good place to start.

Comment: Stay away from recursion , and use it only if you have to

Comment: As yourself this: What is the factorial of 5?  The answer is simple: "It's the 5 times the factorial of 4".  What's the factorial of 4?  It's 4 times the factorial of 3.  (etc.)

Comment: @RiteshK, so no one should bother to learn or try to understand it?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils who said not to learn

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils i said use it only if u can tackle it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you invoke `fact(5)`, here is how it will work:

```
fact(5)
    5*fact(4)
        4*fact(3)
            3*fact(2)
                2*fact(1)
                    2*1=2 //(since if n==1, 1 is returned directly
                result=2
            result=3*2
        result=4*3*2
    result=5*4*3*2
result=120
```

Recursion simply means you invoke a method within itself, usually after manipulating the argument to suit your end result (`n - 1` in this case). You also make sure you define a terminal condition (`n==1` in this case). Internally, the variables are pushed on to a stack to be remembered for every invocation, but that's probably a discussion for another day

Comment: OK kaykay, i kind of get it, i have tried re-running the program using break points and stepping through it to see what is happening to the variables as well, still find it annoyingly puzzling but your explanation has helped me somewhat clear the muddy water.  Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

The factorial of a number n is defined as:
n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 1 , meaning multiply n by all the positive integers less than n.
In you example this is simply reversed, so you first calculate the factorial of n - 1 and then multiply it by n. Continuing this recursion you calculate the factorial of n - 2, n - 3 and so on, until you have to calculate the factorial of 1. In this case you simply return 1 itself and go back into the recursion chain calculating the factorials for 2, 3, ... n - 1, n.

Comment: Seriously, does this answer have anything bad?