# Using recursion for a void print method

Tags: java, recursion

for the first problem of my homework it involves printing out a string of asterisks via a void method using recursion. The number of asterisks printed is based on 2 to the power of n (with n being the parameter of the method).

i.e.

print(1) prints out "**"

print(2) prints out "****"
etc.

honestly the only thing I have so far is this, but it doesn't use recursion.

```
public void print(int num) {
int sum = (int) Math.pow(2, num);
for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

I've been stuck for hours and have no idea how to go about it so if anyone is willing to help I'd be super grateful!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247958/recursion-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
void print(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
    } else {
        print(num - 1);
        print(num - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read upon recursion first. Just be sure of what's your terminating condition. And then play around.

```
public void printUtil(int num) {
// just a util method to get the sum
int sum = (int) Math.pow(2, num); 
print(sum);
}

public void print(int sum){
if(sum == 0) return; // terminating condition
System.out.print("*");
print(--sum); // function calling itself
}
```

Read first. And if still in doubt, then ask! :)

Comment: The most likely expected solution would use two recursive calls that print half of the asterisks each.

Comment: thanks for replying! I had a similar thought process on how your code is laid out, but the only problem I'm running into is that it's all supposed to be in a single print method, so if you calculated sum at the beginning of it, it would end up printing the asterisks for 2^3, then 2^2, etc. which would be too many.

Comment: This code is throwing `StackOverflow`, if you have tried it on your system.

Comment: My bad. I applied post decrement, instead of pre. corrected now.